# Find all possible paths from lists with adjacent elements in Prolog?

Tags: list, recursion, path, prolog

I apologize in advance for the awkward title as it's a bit hard to put clearly in just a few words.

The goal is to find all possible paths and the total energy used from one "room" to another based on the input rooms. So the list [r1,r2,3] would mean you can travel from room 1 to room 2, and from room 2 to room 1, and it would take 3 energy either way. You are **not** allowed to travel to a room previously traveled to.

Here is the list of lists that represent which rooms can be traveled too.

```
adjacent([[r1,r2,8],[r1,r3,2],[r1,r4,4],[r2,r3,7],[r3,r4,1],[r2,r5,2],[r4,r6,5],[r6,r3,9],[r3,r5,3]]).
```

And here is my code which does correctly find a path, however all future possible paths are just repeating previous rooms because I'm unsure on how to implement that functionality. I figured I could simply use not member(PosPath, Paths) since Paths hold the list of all previously traveled to elements but it seems like it adds PosPath to Paths sometime beforehand so it always fails.

```
trip(Start,End,[Start,End],Energy):- adjacent(List), member([Start,End,Energy],List).

trip(Start,End,[Start|Paths],TotalE) :- 
                    adjacent(List),
                    member([Start,PosPath,E], List),
                    % not member(PosPath, Paths),
                    trip(PosPath,End,Paths,PathE).
                    % TotalE is E+PathE.
```

Output:

```
?- trip(r1, r6, Path, TotalE).
Path = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r6]
Total = Total
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
Path = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r6, r3, r4, r6]
Total = Total
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
Path = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r6, r3, r4, r6, r3, r4, r6]
TotalE = TotalE
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rooms in `[r1,r2,3]` represent a bidirectional path I would suggest a predicate that describes this symmetry, let's call it from_to_cost/3:

```
from_to_cost(X,Y,C) :-
   adjacent(L),
   member([X,Y,C],L).
from_to_cost(X,Y,C) :-
   adjacent(L),
   member([Y,X,C],L).
```

For the calling predicate I would suggest a somewhat more descriptive name, say start_end_path_cost/4, that correspond to your predicate trip/4. For the predicate that describes the actual relation two additional arguments are needed: An accumulator to sum up the cost of the path, that starts at `0` and a list of visited rooms that starts with the first room as the single element `[S]`:

```
start_end_path_cost(S,E,P,C) :-
   s_e_p_c_(S,E,P,C,0,[S]).
```

The actual relation has to describe two cases:

1) If the start-room and the end-room are equal the path is found. Then the cost and the accumulator are equal as well and the path is empty.

2) Otherwise there is an intermediary room that has not been visited yet and can be reached from `S`:

```
s_e_p_c_(E,E,[],C,C,_Visited).
s_e_p_c_(S,E,[X|Path],C,C0,Visited) :-
   maplist(dif(X),Visited),
   from_to_cost(S,X,SXC),                
   C1 is C0+SXC,
   s_e_p_c_(X,E,Path,C,C1,[X|Visited]).
```

Now your example query finds all solutions and terminates:

```
?- start_end_path_cost(r1, r6, Path, TotalE).
Path = [r2, r3, r4, r6],
TotalE = 21 ;
Path = [r2, r3, r6],
TotalE = 24 ;
Path = [r2, r5, r3, r4, r6],
TotalE = 19 ;
Path = [r2, r5, r3, r6],
TotalE = 22 ;
Path = [r3, r4, r6],
TotalE = 8 ;
Path = [r3, r6],
TotalE = 11 ;
Path = [r4, r6],
TotalE = 9 ;
Path = [r4, r3, r6],
TotalE = 14 ;
false.
```

And the most general query finds all 137 solutions for your given connections and terminates as well:

```
?- start_end_path_cost(S, E, Path, TotalE).
S = E,
Path = [],
TotalE = 0 ;
S = r1,
E = r2,
Path = [r2],
TotalE = 8 ;
S = r1,
E = r3,
Path = [r2, r3],
TotalE = 15 ;
.
.
.
S = r5,
E = r1,
Path = [r3, r6, r4, r1],
TotalE = 21 ;
S = r5,
E = r2,
Path = [r3, r6, r4, r1, r2],
TotalE = 29 ;
false.
```

---

### Edit:

Concerning your question in the comments: yes it is possible. You can define a predicate that describes the first argument to not be an element of the list that's the second argument, let's call it nonmember/2:

```
nonmember(_A,[]).
nonmember(A,[H|T]):-
   dif(A,H),
   nonmember(A,T).
```

Then you can replace the maplist goal in s_e_p_c_/6 by nonmember/2 like so:

```
s_e_p_c_(E,E,[],C,C,_Visited).
s_e_p_c_(S,E,[X|Path],C,C0,Visited) :-
   nonmember(X,Visited),                  % <- here
   from_to_cost(S,X,SXC),
   C1 is C0+SXC,
   s_e_p_c_(X,E,Path,C,C1,[X|Visited]).
```

With this change the queries yield the same results.

Comment: Is there anyway to implement this without the maplist/2 predicate?